# Faster for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix, indexing

I want to extract only the rows matched by a particular index from the matrix.
Is there a way to speed up the for loop?

```
for(x in 1:dim(gene)[1]){
   for(y in 1:dim(geno)[1]){
      if(grepl(gene[x,2], geno[y], fixed = TRUE)){
         geno_gene <- rbind(geno_gene, geno[y,2:dim(geno)[2]])
         next
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Share a bit of the `gene` and `geno` datasets. What is the actual problem? Is it slow? Compared to what?

At the very least your loop is subject to R's copy-on-modify behaviour. Using the `address` function from `pryr` we can see that after we call `rbind` that your object `m` now is a copy of it's former self:

```
library(pryr)

m <- matrix(1:6, nrow = 3, ncol = 2)
address(m)
new_row <- c(8, 9)
m <- rbind(m, new_row)
address(m)
```

Matrix m changes address after `rbind`:

```
> m <- matrix(1:6, nrow = 3, ncol = 2)
> address(m)
[1] "0x18a0d4737f0"
> new_row <- c(8, 9)
> m <- rbind(m, new_row)
> address(m)
[1] "0x18a0fcb7450"
```

Which means that R has created a copy of `m`, bound the new row to it, assigned the name `m` to the copy and leave it to the garbage collector to discard of the original version of `m`. And it does this for each iteration of your loop. This is a well-known mechanism why R loops can be slow. Read from Hadley Wickham [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Performance.html) for more information.

One potential way out is to assess if the function your loop implements can be replaced by vectorized function in R (and there are many vectorized functions).